How to smooth a 3D surface plot?
i have plotted a surface plot that looks really nice, but its not smooth. I want advice how to smooth 
Here is the code chunk :

fuel_consumption_vals = below_torque_df["Fuel Consumption (kg/h)"].values

# Create a grid for plotting
rpm_grid, torque_grid = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(rpm_vals.min(), rpm_vals.max(), 100),
    np.linspace(torque_vals.min(), torque_vals.max(), 100)
)

# Interpolate fuel consumption values on the grid
fuel_consumption_grid = griddata((rpm_vals, torque_vals), fuel_consumption_vals, 
                                 (rpm_grid, torque_grid), method="cubic")

# Plotting 3D Surface Plot of Fuel Consumption
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
surf = ax.plot_surface(rpm_grid, torque_grid, fuel_consumption_grid, cmap=cm.viridis, edgecolor="none")
ax.set_xlabel("RPM")
ax.set_ylabel("Torque (Nm)")
ax.set_zlabel("Fuel Consumption [g/kWh]")
ax.set_title("3D Surface Plot of Fuel Consumption")
ax.zaxis.labelpad = 2 # Adjust the position of the z-axis label
ax.zaxis._axinfo['juggled'] = (1, 2, 0)  # Reorder the axis, z first
fig.colorbar(surf, ax=ax, shrink=0.5, aspect=6)
plt.savefig("3d_Fuel_consumption.png")  # Save as PNG file
plt.show()

